# Annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

My flow is not forwarded to my controller..And I am getting a warning like:

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spectrum_Inverntory/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

-This is my web.xml

```html
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="2.5">
   <display-name>Spectrum_Inventory</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-
   class>
   </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

-And this is dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spectrum" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" 

class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix"><value>/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
     </bean> 

    <bean id="properties"

  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>WEB-INF/mysql.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>     
    </beans>
```

**
  - InventoryController.java
 **

```java
package com.spectrum.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Spectrum_Inverntory")
public class InventoryController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public String viewProducts(Model model,HttpServletRequest request){

        return "index";
       }        


}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>index here</title>
</head>
<body>
hiiiii

<jsp:forward page="hello"></jsp:forward>

</body>
</html>
```

It is going upto 
     but not hitting my controller... Please help
I am unable to know the exact reason for it.
    My flow is not going in my controller..And I am getting a warning like :
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spectrum_Inverntory/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: `/hello` actually returns an `index`!! And your jsp's name is `welcome`!!

Comment: It is going into welcome.jsp first as i have included it in welcomefile list. After that i am expecting it to go into my controller. I have even placed a debugger there but it is not going there. i have tried both "/hello" and "hello" as value in request mapping. Is there something wrong in dispatcher-servlet ?

Comment: @AjayRawat what is the name of your deployed application?

Comment: try removing `@RequestMapping(value = "/Spectrum_Inverntory")` from your controller.

Comment: Got my mistake.. using absolute path here ..<jsp:forward page="Spectrum_Inverntory/hello"></jsp:forward>.. Thank you all :)